# nightwatchjs test to check element is inactive by checking css attribute value not working

Tags: automation, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I'm testing to check an element on the page is inactive, said element doesn't have a 'disabled' property so I decided to check the class attribute. My test is passing even when I run it for the condition where attribute='navigation' but test is checking for attribute='navigation inactive'
Open to other solutions also.

**Element when active:**

`<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">`

**Element when inactive:**

`<nav class="navigation inactive" role="navigation">`

**Nightwatch test code:**

`.expect.section(`@${elementName}`).to.have.attribute('class').which.equals('navigation inactive');`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi Chit,

You could try `contains` instead of `equals`. E.g. .expect.section(@${elementName}).to.have.attribute('class').which.contains('inactive');

Comment: Thanks! I did use that eventually but still didn't work consistently, I figured out the issue. The menu was initially loading as inactive in the DOM for a split second, so had to wait for it to load fully before my assertion.

Comment: I am glad you solve the issue:)